# Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I want to use an applet to change a repository. To do this I wrote the following code:

LoadOntology:

```
package owlapi.loader;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.io.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.DefaultPrefixManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLEntityRenamer;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class LoadOntology {
    private static String             ontologyDir   = "./owlapi/loader/featurepool.owl";
    private static OWLOntology        localOntology;
    private static OWLOntologyManager manager;
    private static OWLDataFactory     factory;
    private static PrefixManager      pm            = new DefaultPrefixManager("http://wise.vub.ac.be/Members/lamia/variability/Feature_Assembly/FAM.owl#");

public LoadOntology() {
    manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
    File file = new File(ontologyDir);
    try {
        localOntology = manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(file);
        System.out.println("Loaded ontology: " + localOntology);
        factory = manager.getOWLDataFactory();
        }   
    catch (UnparsableOntologyException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not parse the ontology: " + e.getMessage());
        Map<OWLParser, OWLParserException> exceptions = e.getExceptions();
        for (OWLParser parser : exceptions.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("Tried to parse the ontology with the " + parser.getClass().getSimpleName() + " parser");
            System.out.println("Failed because: " + exceptions.get(parser).getMessage());
        }
    }
    catch (UnloadableImportException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not load import: " + e.getImportsDeclaration());
        OWLOntologyCreationException cause = e.getOntologyCreationException();
        System.out.println("Reason: " + cause.getMessage());
    }
    catch (OWLOntologyCreationException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not load ontology: " + e.getMessage());
    }   
}

public void addInstance(String Class, String individual) {
    OWLClass owlClass = factory.getOWLClass(Class, pm);
    OWLClass superClass = factory.getOWLThing();
    OWLIndividual instance = factory.getOWLNamedIndividual(individual, pm);

    OWLClassAssertionAxiom classAssertion1 = factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(superClass, instance);
    manager.addAxiom(localOntology, classAssertion1);
    OWLClassAssertionAxiom classAssertion2 = factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(owlClass, instance);
    manager.addAxiom(localOntology, classAssertion2);
    System.out.println("Instance added");
}
}
```

InJava (applet loaded in javascript):

```
public class InJava extends Applet{
private static LoadOntology loadedOntology;

public void addInstance(String Class, String individual) {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
     g.drawString("Test", 10, 10);
    loadedOntology = new LoadOntology();
    loadedOntology.addInstance(Class, individual);
    }
}
```

When I load the applet, there is no error at all, but when I try to call the method addInstance:

```
<input type="button" value="call Java Applet method" onClick = 'document.owlapi.addInstance("Abstract_Feature", "New_Test")'>
<APPLET CODE="owlapi/InJava.class" NAME="owlapi" HEIGHT=100 WIDTH=100> </APPLET>
```

The browser throws the error `Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.` After reading some questions about this on stackoverflow, I came only to the conclusion that there has to be something wrong with the plugin.

I added some testing-code to the method (the drawString("Test", 10, 10)) which works, so I suggest that the constructing of the LoadOntology class gives some issues (this class was tested separately in works perfect on its own). Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

*update:* I added the a part of the java class that is used by the applet: the repository loader. All the provided code should compile.

*update:* I didn't use `MASCRIPT/SCRIPTABLE` because the code is based on [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0170.html) example, which works in my current browser (chrome)

*udpate:* You have to include the owlapi jars to the buildpath, which can be downloaded [here](http://owlapi.sourceforge.net/download.html)

Comment: *"Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?"*  We might have a better idea if you link to the broken applet and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of failing code.  BTW - why does that applet not declare `MAYSCRIPT`/`SCRIPTABLE` if it is interacting with JavaScript?  What does the JS do?

Comment: I added some extra information, thanks for your reply

Comment: 1) *"All the provided code should compile."*  Only if you have downloaded the `owlapi` & it is in the compilation class-path.  Neither of which is the case here.  2) If the `owlapi` is indeed required for the applet, it will need to be added to the run-time class-path of the applet. 3) What about that link?  4) `File file = new File(ontologyDir);` That won't work in a sand-boxed applet.  If that resource is on your server, it would not even work for a trusted applet.  In the latter case, access it by URL. 5) What is the structure of the server in terms of location of HTML, class and API Jars?

Comment: BTW - I think you are at the stage where you should get this all working in plain HTML without any JS involvement, which I think is triggering the problem.  But the launch has problems beyond that, that should be sorted first.

Comment: 1) Sorry for that, you do need that owlapi. I added the download to my question. 2) do you mean that all those elements from the owlapi have to be imported in the InJava.java file? 3) I didn't declare 'MAYSCRIPT/SCRIPTABLE' to the code because in that example from the link they didn't use that. 4) For the moment I have only a local version of the file, so not on a server. Could this be solved with only the local file. 5) the HTML is found at the root, while the class and API jars are located in the subdirectory owlapi/

Comment: Right.  This is going to be another saga.  1) My point was I won't do that (less subtle this time)  I will go a lot further than most people in trying to help, but downloading an API just to sort a problem like this? No. 2) They need to be added to the archive attribute. 3) I was not referring to the link at Real's HowTo.  I was talking about a link to the applet on the internet.  You say you have it only on local disk.  Load it up.  You obviously have access to a site.  4) '..solved with only the local file(?)'  Not really.  URLs will work off the local file-system (or WWW or on class-path)..

Comment: Ok thank you for all the information Andrew, it was certainly very helpful

Comment: ..so why not use them? 5) Then the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element should list something like `archive='owlapi/owl1.jar,owlapi/owl2.jar`.  --  Deploying applets is a complex task.  To be honest, I think you have a long road ahead of you before you see this working.  Whether I have the energy for yet another task/help of this proportion, I'm not sure.  But first and foremost, ***get rid of the JS!***

Comment: what do you mean by **get rid of the JS**? is there something wrong with the call of my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the fragments I know, I suggest trying this HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
<APPLET 
    CODE="owlapi.InJava" 
    NAME="owlapi" 
    archive="owlapi/owl1.jar,owlapi/owl2.jar"
    HEIGHT=100 
    WIDTH=100> 
</APPLET>  
</body>
</html>
```

This HTML embeds an applet 'statically' - without using JavaScript.  The class-name (the `code` attribute) should be the fully qualified name of the class, as opposed to the file name.  Though the latter is generally tolerated, it is not correct.  It shows how to import the API from the `owlapi` directory, change the names as required.

Also of concern is mixing loose class files and Jars.  This tends to confuse both the developer and the JRE.  If instead the `owlapi.InJava` class was put inside `my.jar`, and that Jar put in the same directory as the rest, a `codebase` could be added and the `archive` paths made shorter.  Like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<APPLET 
    CODE="owlapi.InJava" 
    NAME="owlapi" 
    codebase="owlapi"
    archive="my.jar,owl1.jar,owl2.jar"
    HEIGHT=100 
    WIDTH=100> 
</APPLET>  
</body>
</html>
```

This is not valid HTML.  It is just a test to check the basics.  Later, you'd need to make it valid HTML and (probably) deploy the applet using the `deployJava.js` mentioned in the [applet info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: Thank you, with your help I succeeded to load in the repository and to change the internal representation of the repository. The only part where I have still problems with is the part where I want to save the changes to the file. Like you said before, I fear that there isn't a simple solution to this?

Comment: *"The only part where I have still problems with.."*  No, wrong.  Getting a working applet on your machine is about 5% of what it takes to get an applet working on the net (for the developer to view).  It amounts to around 1% of what it takes to get an applet on the net, working for most visitors. *"..is the part where I want to save the changes"*  You want to ***write to files?***  Actually, hold the answer to that for your next question, since it seems the *"Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject in javascript"* has been solved and *this* question is answered, right?  'Saga'.  ;)

Comment: The applet will only be used offline and is part of an offline ontology visualizer, so I don't need the applet to work on the net. When I want to save / write to the file I get that same error (calling method on NPObject). If it is better to start a new question anyway, I can do that.

Comment: For further attention, ask another question.